# Fedora occasionally freezes when entering Sleep Mode

Tags: fedora, ssd, suspend, nvme

Fedora occasionally freezes when entering Sleep Mode.

I bought an Samsung 970 Evo Plus NVME SSD for my PC (AMD Ryzen CPU and a AMD Radeon GPU. Both are a few years old.)

Last night the computer successfully entered Sleep Mode:

- The screen turned black
- the RGB lights of the CPU Fan turned off as expected.
- This morning I could wake the computer from sleep via power button.

This morning I tried again
This time the PC failed to enter Sleep Mode:

- The screen turned black
- but the RGB lights stayed on.
- After pressing the keyboard, the screen showed the lock screen, but keyboard and mouse did not respond.
- However, the clock on the lock screen, kept updating.
  Restarting the PC resolves the issue.

The NVME SSD has the most recent Firmware according to fwupdmgr and Samsung Magician.

Also: I have been using Kubuntu on a SATA-SSD without Sleep Mode hickups for some time now.

Do you think I should return the NVME SSD?

**edit1:**

1. The error occured another time on 19. Octobre 2023, 13:43. Here is the dmesg from after I restarted the PC: https://pastebin.com/rgABktYm
   If you need dmesg from BEFORE the restart, please send me a link on how to do so. Thank you.
2. The built-in app "Problem Reporting" reports *"A kernel problem has occurred, but your kernel is broken (flags:GW). Explanation: W - Taint on warning. Kernel maintainers cannot analyze reports of damaged kernels."* and this dmesg: https://pastebin.com/6nctj7VL
   But this issue seems to be logged every time the PC goes to sleep, even if successfully, so I am not sure if it has to do with the sleep issue.

Comment: I think you should provide `dmesg` after the system fails to suspend.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thank you! I added two dmesg logs in the question, see "edit1".

Comment: You've got a ton of errors from your GPU driver and a number of `Refused to change power state from` errors. I would update the BIOS to the latest version first. If it doesn't help, try booting with `pcie_aspm=off` and see if it helps.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Good news. I have updated the BIOS as you recommended. Since then Sleep Mode has been working fine during the last 10 attempts. I will comment again once I am sure the issue is resolved. Thank you for helping me. PS: I use an ASrock Pro 450M. I updated it from BIOS 3.9 to 5.7 (the latest non-beta BIOS). ASRock actually warns about updating the BIOS when using a CPU like I do, but I updated it anway ("ASRock do NOT recommend updating this BIOS if you are going to use Pinnacle, Raven or Summit Ridge CPU on your system.").

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments (I can't comment myself, not enough reputation), the kernel logs show some possible GPU-related errors.

Another thing I notice is the absence of lines signaling that GPU firmware is loaded. On my own system I see a dozen lines like this:

`[Thu Oct 19 01:10:03 2023] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/navy_flounder_sos.bin`

Check that `amd-gpu-firmware` is installed, I think it should be pulled with `linux-firmware`. If not, install `linux-firmware` and reboot, and then check in logs (`dmesg`) if you now see lines like above.

(I am certain that there are firmware files for AMD GPUs in this package, whereas it is unclear to me that `fwupdmgr` has any.)

Comment: Thank you. Updating the BIOS solved the problem, see comment above. `dmesg` still reports `amdgpu: last message was failed ret is 255`, but the computer suspends and resumes now.